# How to retrieve a KeyVault Certificate on Thumbprint

Tags: c#, azure-keyvault

I'm trying to do something simple (at least I would expect it to be), how to retrieve a certificate based on it Thumbprint in Azure KeyVault?

Our system retrieves a signed JWToken and on its header it contains the 'kid' containing the Thumbprint of certificate of which the JWToken was signed. I need to find the certificate based on that Thumbprint for validation. With the Azure KeyVault SDK (C# core) there seems to be no-way to retrieve a certificate based on it Thumbprint.

Since there could be different versions of a certificate (each having a different Thumbprint) I cannot use `await client.GetSecretAsync(KvBaseUrl, CertificateName)`. I created the following code:

```cs
public async static Task<X509Certificate2> GetCertificateByThumbprintAsync(this KeyVaultClient client, string kvBaseUrl, string certificateName, string thumbprint )
{
    var allVersionsAsGetTasks = (await client.GetCertificateVersionsAsync(kvBaseUrl, certificateName).ConfigureAwait(false))
        .Select(x => client.GetCertificateAsync(x.Identifier.Identifier))
        .ToList();

    var allCertificates = await Task.WhenAll(allVersionsAsGetTasks).ConfigureAwait(false);

    var correctCertificate = allCertificates.Select(x => new X509Certificate2(x.Cer))
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Thumbprint == thumbprint);

    if (correctCertificate == null)
        throw new Exception($"Certificate with thumbprint '{thumbprint}' was not found");

    return correctCertificate;
}
```

I get the certificate, but it seems like a lot of work and a lot of unnecessary calls to the KeyVault (the `Task.WhenAll` code).

**Is there a simpler way to do this?**

<s>The `client.GetCertificateVersionsAsync(..)` code returns a `CertificateItem` which contains a X509Thumbprint property of type `byte[]`. I seem to be unable to transform the `byte[]` as string. I tried Base64 and UTF8 but both gives me a weird result not containing the thumbprint.</s>

**Update**

Thanks to a colleague we found a quicker way to retrieve the correct certificate

```cs
public async static Task<CertificateBundle> GetCertificateByThumbprintAsync(this KeyVaultClient client, string kvBaseUrl, string certificateName, string thumbprint)
{
    var certificateVersion = (await client.GetCertificateVersionsAsync(kvBaseUrl, certificateName).ConfigureAwait(false))
        .FirstOrDefault(x => BitConverter.ToString(x.X509Thumbprint).Replace("-", "") == thumbprint);

    if (certificateVersion == null)
        throw new Exception($"Certificate with thumbprint '{thumbprint}' was not found");

    return await client.GetCertificateAsync(certificateVersion.Identifier.Identifier);
}
```

**Update 2**
We are using Azure Managed Identities to access KeyVault. We are using the following code:

```cs
private async Task<KeyVaultClient> GetClientAsync()
{
    var provider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();

    logger.LogInformation("Trying to retrieve a token for KeyVault communication.");

    try
    {
        await provider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://vault.azure.net").ConfigureAwait(false);

        logger.LogInformation("Token for KeyVault received");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        logger.LogError("Could not retrieve access for KeyVault communication.");
        throw;
    }

    return new KeyVaultClient(new AuthenticationCallback(provider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your update, I am struggling in the part of constructing the KeyVaultClient and can't find a straight forward sample for .net core about that, can you please share that as part of the question?

Comment: @Marzouk I've updated the question to create the KeyVaultClient. I hope it helps.